# KDE Neon System Monitor Indicators not working after upgrade to 5.23

Tags: widget, kde-plasma

I have KDE neon and recently it was upgraded to the latest version, 5.23. The problem I have that System Monitor Indicator widgets no longer working, they are just empty, like this:

[image: Empty system monitor widget]

When I open settings for that widget and go to Sensors page, there are no sensors available

[image: No sensors in System Monitor widget settings]

I have the same issue on at least 2 different installations. Strangely, I can't find any informaiton about it anywhere. Is there any fix available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have ksystemstats installed by running it in Konsole.

```
ksystemstats
```

If it appears not found or not installed, try to install it.

```
sudo apt install ksystemstats
```

then try again running in konsole (you will see that it initializes)

```
ksystemstats
```

and finally open System Monitor.

Comment: Thanks. Although it was fixed automatically with recent update, The fix was... you guessed it: they've added `ksystemstats` as a dependency to `plasma-systemmonitor`.